# Simplest Examples for Tensors in Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, tensor-products, tensors

In my attempt to gain *some* sort of understanding of tensor products (of vector spaces), and looking at the [corresponding nLab entry](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/tensor+product+of+vector+spaces) (or [Wikipedia's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product)), I tried to consider a very basic example. Unfortunately, even there, I'm stuck.

---

Let $V=W=U=\mathbb{R}^2$ (with the standard bases).

Let $B : V \times W \to U$ be bilinear.

Let $B_\otimes : V\otimes W \to U$ be linear and such that $B_\otimes(v\otimes w) = B(v,w)$ for all $v\in V$ amd $w\in W$.

\begin{align*}
    v=\begin{bmatrix} v_1 \\ v_2 \end{bmatrix},\ w=\begin{bmatrix} w_1 \\ w_2 \end{bmatrix},\quad & B(v,w) = \begin{bmatrix} v_1 + w_2 \\ v_2 - w_1 \end{bmatrix}. \text{Edit: Not bilinear} \\
    v \otimes w = \begin{bmatrix} v_1w_1 & v_1w_2 \\ v_2w_1 & v_2w_2 \end{bmatrix},\quad & B_\otimes(v \otimes w) = {?}
\end{align*}

---

How could I extract, say, $v_1$, using only some linear combination of $v_iw_j$'s? Or is this not what is being asked by this example? How else can I explicitly write $B(v\otimes w)$?

I hope at least that what I already wrote of the example is not grossly unfounded.

Any 'other' simple and instructive examples of tensors / tensor products of vector spaces would, of course, also be much appreciated.

Comment: Well this isn't going to work because the $B$ you've provided isn't bilinear. Once you choose a bilinear map $B$, then it should be fairly easy to see how you can multiply components of $v \otimes w$ to get that map.

Comment: @OsamaGhani [Is this always the case?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3669629/)

Comment: Someone has responded to your question by now, so yes, this is always true