# Bilinear Maps between Finite-Dimensional Vector Spaces & the Outer Product

Tags: linear-algebra, multilinear-algebra, outer-product

**Theorem**. *A function $f : \mathbb{R}^{n_1} \times \mathbb{R}^{n_2} \to \mathbb{R}^{n_3}$ is [bilinear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_map) iff each component of $f(v,w)$ is a linear combination of terms of the form $v_iw_j$, where $v=\begin{bmatrix}v_1&\cdots&v_{n_1}\end{bmatrix}^T$ and $w=\begin{bmatrix}w_1&\cdots&w_{n_2}\end{bmatrix}^T$ (i.e., terms from the [outer product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_product) $v\otimes w$ of $v$ and $w$).*

*Proof* ($\impliedby$). Follows immediately from the [field axioms](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FieldAxioms.html) of $\mathbb{R}$.

*Proof* ($\implies$). This is the question. Or is the statement not even correct? I couldn't come up with a counterexample.

This is a sort of "follow up question" for this other question of mine: [Simplest Examples for Tensors in Linear Algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3668156/).

Does this theorem, if correct, generalize nicely to multilinear functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First write 
$$
v = \sum_{i=1}^{n_1} v_ie_i \quad \textrm{and} \quad w = \sum_{j=1}^{n_2} w_j \hat{e}_j
$$ 
where $e_1,\dots,e_{n_1}$ is the standard basis for $\mathbb R^{n_1}$ and $\hat{e}_1,\dots,\hat{e}_{n_2}$ for $\mathbb R^{n_2}$. Now, since $f$ is bilinear,
$$
f(u,v) = \sum_{i=1}^{n_1} v_if(e_i,w) = \sum_{i=1}^{n_1} \sum_{j=1}^{n_2} v_iw_j f(e_i,\hat{e}_j).
$$

Comment: This looks like it *would* generalize easily (aside from the index soup) for multilinear functions, right? Something like $f(v_1,\ldots,v_n) = \sum_{i_1=\{ 1,\ldots,n_1 \}, \ldots, i_n=\{ 1,\ldots,n_n \} } v_{1_{i_1}} \cdots v_{n_{i_n}} f( e_{i_1}, \ldots, e_{i_n} )$?

Comment: Yes, it generalizes easily.